# Strange problem with wp_get_attachment_image_src database (db) query count

Tags: loop, query, attachments

I have a purchased theme that has a custom WordPress loop in it that looks for image attachments via `wp_get_attachment_image_src`.  It does this by doing the following:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'widget-image-thumb' ) );
```

I can't for the life of me figure out why but this is generating massive amounts of queries against the database.  What's even more strange is the loop is only 5 posts and if I take the 5 post ids returned from `get_post_thumbnail_id()` and manually put them in like the following:

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( 44505, 'widget-image-thumb' );
```

The query count is fine.  I thought it was an issue of the returned value from `get_post_thumbnail_id()` but despite casting it and doing more rigorous checking I can't make the two functions work together.  Per the codex I also tried doing the following:

```
<?php
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_status' => null, 'post_parent' => $post->ID ); 
$attachments = get_posts($args);
if ($attachments) {
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
        echo apply_filters( 'the_title' , $attachment->post_title );
        the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID , false );
    }
}
?>
```

Here is the full code that's being used right now:

```
    <?php
    $recent_posts = new WP_Query(array(
        'showposts' => 5,
        'cat' => 'all',
    ));
    ?>

    <?php while($recent_posts->have_posts()): $recent_posts->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="block-item-small">
    <?php 
        if(has_post_format('video') || has_post_format('audio') || has_post_format('gallery')) {
            $icon = '<span class="' . get_post_format() . '-icon"></span>';
        } else {
            $icon = '';
            }
    ?>
        <?php if($images && has_post_thumbnail()): ?>
        <?php $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(), 'widget-image-thumb'); ?>
        <div class="block-image"><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><img src="<?php echo $image[0]; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"  width='50' height='50' /></a><?php echo $icon; ?></div>
        <?php else: ?>
        <div class="block-image"><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/thumbnail.png&w=60&h=60" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>"  width='50' height='50' /></a><?php echo $icon; ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <h2><a href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>' title='<?php the_title(); ?>'><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <span class="block-meta"><?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>, <?php comments_popup_link(); ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <!-- END WIDGET -->
    <?php
    echo $after_widget;
```

Comment: Try `update_post_thumbnail_cache( $recent_posts );` right after you assign the query.

Comment: @TheDeadMedic That appears to reduce the query count by between 50-100 queries but if I comment out that the `wp_get_attachment_image_src` part it goes down by ballpark 300 queries.  Seems really strange that manually specifying an integer post id fixes the problem.